# Search filter script is hiding unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script where a search input field hides any items (spread throughout a few unordered lists) which don't contain any of text in the search input field, and it is mostly working in all the ways I want it to. I have done something similar before which all worked fine.

However this time as well as hiding all the items that don't match the input text, it also hides any parent containers if all of it's children list items are hidden (because none of them contain the searched input text).

For some reason this time when I add the parent hiding functionality it's hiding some items that actually match the inputted search text and should be showing still, but then it's not hiding others items that match and I can't figure out why.

I'll add the basic script below to help:

```js
let filterList = [];
let filters = document.querySelectorAll('ul.list-filters a');

// Add the search input field:

let tEl = document.querySelector('#productListLeft');
let nEl = document.createElement('input');
nEl.setAttribute('id' ,  'filterSearch');
nEl.setAttribute('type' ,  'text');
nEl.setAttribute('placeholder' ,  'Search for filters');
tEl.prepend(nEl);

// Filter/hide items if they don't matched seached input text:

let filtersSearch = document.querySelector('#filterSearch');

for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    let filterName = filters[i].querySelector('span:first-of-type').textContent.toLowerCase(); 
    filterList.push(filterName);
}

console.log(filterList);


filtersSearch.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let text = filtersSearch.value.toLowerCase();

    for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        if (filterList[i].indexOf(text) < 0) {
            filters[i].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            filters[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    
    // Hiding the parent div if all children are hidden (THIS IS THE PART THAT INCONCISTENTLY BREAKS THE FUNCTIONALITY AT SOME POINT:)

    let parentFilter = document.querySelectorAll(".filterSet");
    let visCheck = true;
    
    for(i = 0; i < parentFilter.length; i++) {
        let children = parentFilter[i].querySelectorAll('ul.list-filters a');
        for(x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
            let child = children[x];
            
            if(child.style.display != "none") {
                visCheck = true;
            } else {
                visCheck = false;
            }
        }
        
        if (visCheck == false) {
            parentFilter[i].style.display = "none";
        } else if (visCheck == true) {
            parentFilter[i].style.display = "block";            
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="productListLeft">
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 1</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Foo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Bar</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Ball</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 2</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Chair</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Kind</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Salt</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Horror</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 3</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>King</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Stagged</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tomatoe</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Grilled</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run the code snippet and enter just `r` in the search input field it hides all the items that don't have an r in them, and then also hides the parent container if all the items are hidden, which is correct. However if you just enter `f` in the search input field it hides even items that have an f in them (like the first item 'foo'), and I can't figure out why.

I have actually got a jQuery solution (to replace the issue part of hiding the parent if the children items are all hidden) which works just as I need it too without the same issue, but I want to keep it as just JS and have struggled to translate the same code in JS (especially the `$(this).find("ul.list-filters a").map(function(){` part.

Here's the code in case it's easier for someone to help convert it to the JS version:

```
$('.filterSet').map(function(){
    let visCheck = true;
    $(this).find("ul.list-filters a").map(function(){
       if ( $(this).css("display") != "none" ) {
        visCheck = false;
       }
    });

    if ( visCheck == true ) {
       $(this).css("display", "none");
    } else {
       $(this).css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Help to solve either the issue with my original JS script or replicating the jQuery version in JS would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The logic to determine whether to set visCheck is not correct.  Start with it equal to false, and only set it to true if you find an element that is visible.  (Do not have the else).  You could accomplish much the same thing more compactly using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Also never waste a map on something you do not need in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damzaky already provided a perfect fix for your problem (+1). In case you are interested in a slightly shorter version, here is one based on an `Array.some()` loop:

```js
document.getElementById("productListLeft").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",`<input type="text" placeholder="Search for filters" oninput="flt(this)">`);
function flt(el){
 const f=el.value.toLowerCase(), 
       sets=document.querySelectorAll(".filterSet");
 sets.forEach(set=>{
  const lnks=[...set.querySelectorAll("a")]
  lnks.forEach(a=>
   a.style.display=a.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(f)?"":"none"
  )
  set.style.display=lnks.some(l=>l.style.display=="")?"":"none";
 });
 
}
```

```html
<div id="productListLeft">
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 1</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Foo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Bar</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Ball</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 2</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Chair</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Kind</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Salt</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Horror</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 3</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>King</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Stagged</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tomatoe</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Grilled</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did test and your code worked great too and so efficient. I haven't come across the Array.some before so thanks for your code example, there's parts of your code I need to work out to understand it better, but it should help me learn it. I also wanted this to be mostly my code for the build so Damzakay's answer does make more sense for the bounty needs but I do wish I could upvote yours more too as it's great.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a lot of things that i'd like to improve in your code to make it cleaner, but I don't want to complicate things for you. Without changing your code too much, the simple fix is to add `break` statement inside the if block like this:

```
...
            if(child.style.display != "none") {
                visCheck = true;
                break;
            }
...
```

so why do we need that break? because if we don't add break, even if there is a non-hidden child, it will become false again if there are other hidden child after that non-hidden child.

Here is the updated snippet:

```js
let filterList = [];
let filters = document.querySelectorAll('ul.list-filters a');

// Add the search input field:

let tEl = document.querySelector('#productListLeft');
let nEl = document.createElement('input');
nEl.setAttribute('id' ,  'filterSearch');
nEl.setAttribute('type' ,  'text');
nEl.setAttribute('placeholder' ,  'Search for filters');
tEl.prepend(nEl);

// Filter/hide items if they don't matched seached input text:

let filtersSearch = document.querySelector('#filterSearch');

for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    let filterName = filters[i].querySelector('span:first-of-type').textContent.toLowerCase(); 
    filterList.push(filterName);
}

filtersSearch.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let text = filtersSearch.value.toLowerCase();

    for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        if (filterList[i].indexOf(text) < 0) {
            filters[i].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            filters[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    
    // Hiding the parent div if all children are hidden (THIS IS THE PART THAT INCONCISTENTLY BREAKS THE FUNCTIONALITY AT SOME POINT:)

    let parentFilter = document.querySelectorAll(".filterSet");
    let visCheck = true;
    
    for(i = 0; i < parentFilter.length; i++) {
        let children = parentFilter[i].querySelectorAll('ul.list-filters a');
        for(x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
            let child = children[x];
            
            if(child.style.display != "none") {
                visCheck = true;
                break;
            } else {
                visCheck = false;
            }
        }
        
        if (visCheck == false) {
            parentFilter[i].style.display = "none";
        } else if (visCheck == true) {
            parentFilter[i].style.display = "block";            
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="productListLeft">
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 1</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Foo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Bar</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Ball</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 2</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Chair</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Kind</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Salt</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Horror</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="filterSet">
    <h4>Filters 3</h4>
    <ul class="list-filters">
      <li><a href="#"><span>King</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Stagged</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tomatoe</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Grilled</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this sorted it. Sorry I went back to looking at this last night and tried a few things until late without success, so I put the bounty on went to bed and only just woke up to see this. I put a lot of effort into this before asking and knew I couldn't have been far off (damn break). Thank you again that one word fixes it and it says in 10 hours I can give you the bounty, so I will. I usually get something fully working before looking at how I can optomise, which I will look at now thanks :)